# Adding an extension to Eclipse without an internet connection

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a problem with eclipse. I would like to install an extension (EGit) but the official site does only provide a classical update site.

The problem is that I am running eclipse on a distant machine that does not have internet access (only my local computer has a connection). The only link between my computer and my distant machine is a distant hard drive that is mounted on the two computers.

The distant machine is a classic linux but the local one is a Windows XP so I can't just use ssh -L (or at least I do not know the way to do it under windows).

Does anybody have an idea to help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [mirroring the update site to a folder](http://www.denoo.info/2009/09/mirroring-eclipse-update-sites/), and then use the folder as a local update site on the machine without internet connection.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Eclipse (same version) installed on your local system, Then you can install plugin through update site. Just check what all it depends on and what additional plugins are downloaded.

Once done with this you can locate new plugins in /plugins folder. Just copy these to your remote machine. This should usually work. But it would sometimes depend upon OS for certain plugins. In your case Local and Target OS is different so there are some chances of this solution not working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already thought to this solution but I haven't tried yet because I do not want to take any risk with my git projects if there's a solution that allow me to install directly on the distant eclipse.

Comment: You can have as many Eclipse installations as you want on your machine. Just unzip Eclipse distro into a different directory and work with that on the connected machine.

Comment: @zvikico but there is difference of OS in case of Elenaher.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse plugins usually depend on other plugins. It's kind of hard to trace the dependencies. It's better to download all dependencies using update site once, and you can distribute to other Eclipse dropins. Eclipse does not recommend overriding plugins directory since it may break existing functioning plugins. For Eclipse 3.4 or newer, you can use dropins which is an Eclipse feature for safe overriding. This way you don’t have to install plugin from update site every time you have to re-install your Eclipse. Read on [How to install Eclipse plugins offline](http://michsan.web.id/content/how-install-eclipse-plugins-offline)